# I'm trying to solve homework with list. Find the second element in the list which starts with "a"

Tags: python

This is my code so far:

```
def get_second_element_starting_with_a(names):
    """Find the second element in the list which starts with "a"."""
    if names != 0 and names != []:
        for name in names[1:]:
            if name.startswith("a"):
                return name
    return None
```

Comment: Its a little sparse, why isn't this working? What is the result you get compared to the expected?

Comment: So after I've found the first "a", I have no knowledge to get to another element that starts with "a".

Comment: Well I only tested with  index 0. So the first element which strats with "a" is index 0. But what if the first element is index 2 and second index 4

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but what do you expect to achieve with `if names != 0`? This will not ensure you anything but the fact that `names` doesn't equal to the number 0. It can still be `None` or 1 or everything else..

Comment: I was checking if the list is empty.

Comment: @Code34 This is what the `and names != []` condition does. The `names != 0` condition just checks if the variable `names` is the number 0. `len(names) != 0` could check if this was an empty list, but then the second condition would be absolute.

Comment: @Aryerez Thank you for explaining.  I can see that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple possible ways:

```
lst = ['anton', 'berta', 'caesar', 'zacharias', 'antonio']

elements_with_a = [item for item in lst if item.startswith('a')]
if len(elements_with_a) > 1:
    print(elements_with_a[1])
    # antonio
```

Or - with an index variable:

```
lst = ['anton', 'berta', 'caesar', 'zacharias', 'antonio']

def get_second_element_starting_with_a(some_lst):
    idx = 0
    for name in some_lst:
        if name.startswith('a'):
            idx += 1
            if idx == 2:
                return name
    return None

print(get_second_element_starting_with_a(lst))
# antonio
```

Or with `filter` and `enumerate`:

```
for (idx, name) in enumerate(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('a'), lst), 1):
    if idx == 2:
        print(name)
        # antonio
```